# Getting value with the post method from <input> PHP/HTML

Tags: php, html, input

I have the following code, i am trying to send the "username" value of the textfield to the next page when i click on the button, unfortunately the value which is being sent is always "    ", what i am doing wrong here?

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]> <html class="lt-ie9 lt-ie8" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]> <html class="lt-ie9" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
    <?php 
     include "../pfe/files/connect.php";
     $page = isset($_POST['page']) ? $_POST['page'] : '';

     if(!$page) {
     $id = $_GET["id"];

    session_start();
                }


    ?>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">

    <?php
     echo'<title>User Page</title>';
    ?>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/new.css">
    <!--[if lt IE 9]><script    src="//html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->

    </head>
    <body>
    <div align="center">

    <?php
    $query1 = "select * from USER where ID=$id";

    $exec1 = $mysql->query($query1) or die("Erreur ...");
    $row1 = $exec1->fetch_array();

     ?>
                <form name="form" method="post">
                <table align=\"center\" border=\"1\ " >
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                    <td><input type="text" name="username" id="username"  placeholder="Username" required value=<?php echo htmlentities($row1["USERNAME"]); ?>></td>
                    <td></tr>

                </thead>
                </table>
                </form>

                <?php

                $username = isset($_POST['username']) ?      $_POST['username'] : '';
                echo' hone \'{$username}\'';

                if(isset($_GET["update"]))
                    {
                    $username2= $_GET["username2"];
    $query1 = "UPDATE USER set USERNAME='$username2' where USER.ID=$id";

    $exec1 = $mysql->query($query1) or die("Error");}
                ?>
                <table>
                <tread>

                    <tr>
                    <td>
                    <?php  $username = isset($_POST['username']) ?   $_POST['username'] : '';
                    echo" <a href=\"../pfe/user.php?  update&id=$id&username2=$username\" class=\"button yellow\">Update</a>  <br>"; ?></td> </tr>


    <?php    



    include "../pfe/files/disconnect.php";
    ?>


                </thead>
                </table>


</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Input value needs quotation value="<?php echo value ?>"

Comment: i dont think this is the problem @luka since the value from the database appears inside the textfield as it is

Comment: Please describe the expected flow. E.g. when (and how) is `$_POST['username']` expected to be set? Could be you want the form to post the data back to the same url, but there is no submit element in the form. And what's that `$_POST['page']`-stuff?

Comment: Do you want to submit the `username` as a field in the form?  There doesn't appear to be a submit button in your code for the form - are you actually submitting the form and requesting the page with POST or just clicking the button and requesting it with GET?

Comment: i guess the submit form is missing, i am trying to send the value of the <input> when edited when pressing the button , but i dont know how to use the submit form when using a customised button, how should i write this submit form ? @VolkerK